# remote access rooted device with broken screen

Tags: cyanogenmod, remote-access, broken-screen

I have a samsung galaxy s1 rooted and using cyanogenmod, yesterday i broke my screen , I need help to remote access it, I got allot of things written down on my memopad allot of things that I need to retrive but I dont seem to make it work(i tried allot of things but mostly i need to find a way to press on that button and activate the debugg mode or smth to let me access the phone) because as far as I remember  everytime I connected my phone on laptop I had to manually turn on debugging mode for access to the phone , even though I already activated it in dev tools. it shows me that I plugged in my device but I cant access it and I cant use any app to remote control it. Anyone can give me a solution?
When I plug it in, on devices I can see the name of my phone, GT-I9000 but thats all I can get access to it...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion 1:

1. Run an ADB shell in ClockworkMod
2. Remount /system in readwrite mode.
3. Add this to /system/build.prop:
   persist.service.adb.enable=1
4. Save the file.

Suggestion 2:

You said that you have installed CyanogenMod. So you probably have a custom recovery, right? You can boot into it, connect your phone to your computer and go to "mounts" -> "mount USB storage".
Then you can access your internal storage.

Suggestion 3:

With a little bit of work you could flash a custom kernel with USB-OTG.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1450298

Please note that you need an external power source (USB-Y cable, powered USB hub; see the link).

Then you can use a mouse and a keyboard to control your phone and access your data.

Comment: i dont know where this "mounts" is on windows 8, can you be more specific?

Comment: It's not in windows, it's in the CWM Recovery on your phone :)

Comment: I dont have a screen and to be sincere , I dont really know much about cwm recovery or how can I access it, I installed adb too but I dont know how to use it :)

Comment: Is your screen black, or is only the touch affected?

Comment: black, I cant see anything, but I know its working because of the buttons and that my windows recognizes it as a device

Comment: and I dont know how to do "Run an ADB shell in ClockworkMod" , tried to look for it but didnt understand much , though I work in IT.

Comment: Steps to enter recovery mode: Turn off your phone. Then press there keys: http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/4151/samsunggalaxysi9000recv.jpg

Comment: yeah, I know that, the phone is in recovery mode but I dont have acces from the computer, is there any tutorial for adb?

Comment: When your phone booted into the recovery, plug it into your computer and press the following keys step by step on your phone: vol+ vol+ power vol+ power. Then your phone should mount USB storage, which means that you can access your files from your computer. Good Luck!